# mySQL include both specific and wider range in date search

Tags: mysql, date

I have a table X with records:

```
rec# start end 
===============
100  2000  2020 
101  2004  2005 
102  2006  2007
```

I try:

```
            SELECT * from X where start >= 2004 and end <= 2005;
```

and

```
            SELECT * from X where start BETWEEN 2004 and 2005;
```

In both cases I (correctly) get rec# 101 as the result.
But I need to also be retrieving rec# 100 because the range (2004-2005) is included in the 2000-2020 record.

Thank you for any help...

Comment: So why shouldn;t rec 102 be returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you have your inequalities around the wrong way:

```
SELECT * FROM X WHERE start <= 2004 AND end >= 2005
```

This will return all records which *contain* the interval `[2004,2005]`.

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d73ee/1/0).

Comment: No, this will give me everything *but* rec# 101 which is not what I want.

Comment: @GeorgeDSeas: Did you click the link?